# Python error: "list object has no attribute ".upper"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently try to program a code in a python that will respond to you if your reply to it is in the list of possible answers. The program example is below.

```
def responce():
    greetings = ["Hello","Hi","Nice to see you!","Greetings","How's it going?","How are you doing?","What's new?","How's your day going?","Hey!"]
    print("\n")
    reply = input(": ")
    lenrep = len(reply)
    tempstore = []
    for i in range(0,lenrep):
        tempstore.append(i)
        z = 0
        while z < 9:
            tempgreet = greetings[z]
            if tempstore.upper() == tempgreet.upper():
                reply = ""
                tempstore = []
                temprandno = random.randint(0,2)
                addon = ["what do you want to know?", "what do you want to talk about?", " "]
                addontext = addon[temprandno]
                text(greet(), + " " + addontext)
                z += 1
        if i == " ":
            tempstore = []
```

Now my question is, why does it come up with the error

```
AttributeError: list object has no attribute 'upper'
```

and is there a way to fix my program to make it work?

Thank you for any response.

Comment: `tempstore` is a list and doesn't have the `upper()` method. Did you mean to look for the word in the list?

Comment: Because a list doesn't have a method `upper()`: `tempstore` is that list. Since it's a list of integers, it's unclear what you want to uppercase about that.

Comment: Yes i did mean to look for the word in list MooingRawr

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tips:

```
    greetingsInUpCases  = [elem.upper() for elem in greetings ]
```

converts **all strings** in greetings list to **uppercase letters**, and the expression

```
    reply.upper() in greetingsInUpCases
```

allow you to decide if the `reply` **is in the current list**. You may use it in `if` statement:

```
    if reply.upper() in greetingsInUpCases:
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped to fix it, it finally works, have upvoted but does not display because of my reputation.